# Shopping Cart implementation in Razor Pages Core 3.1 updating item count label

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to create an anonymous shopping cart, a new user visits the site, they add a product to their shopping cart, a cookie is created storing a user guid and a total item count. The actual cart is stored in the database. Adding a new item calls a server side method using ajax.

my question is how to implement a label in the navbar to show the number of items as the item count changes. adding items does not postback or go to a basket overview.

I was thinking of simply having the shopping cart link and text as a partial which reads the total from the updated cookie and refreshing that but I'm not sure if a partial can be refreshed from another page.

How do other people do it? Simply update the label using Javascript?

Comment: Well. You can either: 1) use `websocket`, or 2) create a `setInterval` and `ajax` to call an endpoing to get the items/nr. of items every x - seconds.
The 2nd approach might be easier for you to do, but make sure x-seconds is not a small number cause you don't want to make the app heavy. If you complete it and you are satisfied, you might want to try the 1st approach as it is more real-time.

Comment: Thanks, I’m not a fan of using a timed loop to update the value in the _layout. I’m not sure if websockets are the way forward, it’s only a label update. There must be some way so refresh a partial in the _layout which will read the cookie value OR using something  like innerhtml?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use partialview. Return a partialview as output when the shopping cart changes. And design the partialview depending on your taste. I enter a code as an example

html code:

```
<span id="framebasket">
     @Html.Partial("_Basket")
</span>
```

_Basket partial:

```html
 <div class="col-level1-14">
      <div class="row-new padding-r-25">
         <span class="color-black style-font-12-sb">@p.ProductName</span>
       </div>
       <div class="row-new padding-r-25">
          <span class="color-black style-font-12-sb">@p.ColorTitle</span>
       </div>
                   
       <div class="row-new padding-r-25">
           <span class="style-font-12-sb color-888">Count: </span>
           <span class="style-font-12-sb color-888">@item.Count</span>
           @if (p.ShowOfferPrice.Value)
            {
                 total = total + (p.OfferPrice * item.Count);
                <span class="float-l style-font-12-sb padding-t-5 color-888">@p.OfferPrice.ToPrice()</span>
            }
            else
            {
              total = total + (p.Price * item.Count);
              <span class="float-l style-font-12-sb padding-t-5 color-888">@p.Price.ToPrice()</span>
            }
      </div>
</div>
```

Script required:

```
<script>
$('.addtobasket').click(function () {
       showLoad();
       var basket = $(this).attr('basket');
       var inst = $('[data-remodal-id=modalbasket]').remodal();

       $.ajax({
         url: "/Basket/AddToBasket",
         data: { basket: basket },
         type: "Post",
         dataType: "Json",
         success: function (result) {
         $("#framebasket").html(result.HtmlBody);
         //this for aler The information was logged into the system to reassure the user
         inst.open();
         closeshowLoad();
        },
        error: function () {
         closeshowLoad();
       }
     });
   });
</script>
```

controller example :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToBasket(string basket)
{
    basket operation ...
    return Json(new JsonData()
    {
       HtmlMsg = "",
       HtmlBody = this.RenderPartialToString("_Basket", lst),
       Success = true,
    });
}
```

This was just a general explanation.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear sorry.. I have a nav bar in my _layout which has a link to the basket page. When the user adds something to the basket I use Ajax to call server side to add the item to the database. I remain on the add to basket page I do not redirect to the basket. I just want to update the link in the layout to say basket (1 item)

Comment: I guess I could just update the label in the Ajax success call